# No associated handles but can't disconnected device

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, safely-remove-hardware

Hullo everyone,

For some reason my laptop refuses to give up my external SSD.
It's been an ongoing issue, and there's even been data loss from it before I realised what was going on it.

When I try to "safely eject" the media it says the drive is currently in use.
When I check the associated handles, the list does not contain anything touching my drive on S:.

What more can I do to figure out what's not allowing me to disconnect the drive?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you safely remove the drive after a cold start? Like if you boot, connect the drive, then safely remove it? Sometimes, some service called by some app will lock some file in that drive and the lock will prevail even after closing the app. If you have Windows 10 try to do a Hard Shutdown.

Comment: Have you tried third-party tools such as LockHunter? https://lockhunter.com/

Comment: Lock hunter was a great suggestion.Looks like explorer.exe still thinks it has windows open to a dozen different directories on the drive.  There's also some handles from System with `s:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$Txflog\$TxfLog.blf`.  Any idea what that is?!